# OS X 'Quick Look' stopped working

Tags: macos, quicklook

I am running the latest updates for my Mac OS X OS and I just realized that Quick Look is not working. Typically I select a file via single click in my finder and press the space bar this would bring up Quick Look. It currently does nothing. 
I looked in the Console and it is not generating any errors. Is there a known fix?

Comment: Please tell me you've tried restarting...

Answer (score 4):

You can invoke quick look manually from the commandline to see if there is something wrong. Open a Terminal and list all available files with the command **ls**. Now run

```
qlmanage -p something
```

Where something would be any item shown by the previous **ls** command. It can be a directory, a file, just about anything. In fact, you can substitute something with a single dot and it should run too.

Running this command will try to open quick look manually, and you can see on the console all the possible warnings/errors which can help you diagnose a problem. For instance, you may get the error *Can't open input server* pointing to a file, which tells you that you have an input manager either incompatible with your current OSX version or just behaving incorrectly in some way.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot but it’s worth mentioning: if you are running SugarSync, it could be what’s preventing you from using Quick Look.

I’m not sure why this is, and I’ve filed a bug report with SugarSync (today). For me the problem with Quick Look not reacting started around the time when I installed SugarSync and disappeared the second after I had uninstalled it ([how-to instructions at SugarSync’s site](https://sugarsync.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/60/~/uninstalling-sugarsync-from-a-mac-os-computer)).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much elias, this was the problem
I didn't have to uninstall, just quit sugarsync manager. I've also sent them a support request.

This article on SugarSync help says that the latest version solves the problem, and suggests the following workaround
The following steps should resolve the issue as a temporary work around until we have an update built into the SugarSync Manager.

In Finder, go to the Applications folder
Right click (or Ctrl click) on SugarSync Manager application
Select Show Package Contents
In the new Finder window that opens, go to Contents/Plugins and delete SugarSyncCMPlugin.cocoa.plugin.
After deleting these files, just restart Finder (or log out and log back in to your computer)
Note:  by deleting the plug-in you are disabling Finder extensions completely. You will lose overlay icons and context menus untill we fix the problem.  We apologize for the inconvenience and will get an update out as soon as possible.

Cheers
B